# List lines from file, and create an option to delete a line

Tags: c#

I'm making a project, and I need to delete lines from file.
Example:
(By reading from a file, like "list.txt")

```
1 Hello DELETE
2 Hi    DELETE
3 Hey   DELETE
```

I've tried thinking of how to do it, but I couldn't find a way to do it. I've also tried searching for it in Google.

Comment: What part are you having trouble with ? Reading the lines ? Presenting a UI on the screen ? Removing lines ? Questions here need to be specific, programming related questions - try breaking your problem into parts, and ask a question here if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deleting lines from text file, *rewrite* would be better option. If you have a every large text file, reading all lines into memory is not optimized much. [`ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) method is down on the way to deal with this case

> When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient.

Assume you have method to check whether a line should be deleted or not:

```
 bool ShouldDeleteLine(string line)
 {
 }
```

The code:

```
 string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

 var lines = File.ReadLines("list.txt")
                    .Where(line => !ShouldDeleteLine(line));

 File.WriteAllLines(tempFile, lines);

 File.Delete("list.txt");
 File.Move(tempFile, "list.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Read all the lines into memory, then write it back to the file excluding the lines you wish to delete. If it is an extremely large file that you can't store in memory all at one time, you can go a few lines at a time and write it to a new file (minus the lines to be deleted). Then, when you're through the original file, go ahead and delete it and rename the new one to the original name.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this:

```
void DeleteLines()
{
    var filePath = @"path/to/file.txt";
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
    File.WriteAllLines(filePath, lines.Where(KeepLine));
}   

bool KeepLine(string line)
{
    // Decide whether to keep this line. The line below for example
    // Keeps all lines except the ones containing the word "Hey".
    return !line.Contains("Hey");
}
```

It's reads the entire file into memory and then write all lines to keep back to the file.